How can ngOnChanges be called only for active tabs in mat-tab-group?
I have a parent component and a child component. When I send the data from parent to child, it is calling the ngOnChanges method in both the child component instances hence causing data to be shared. How can I avoid that?
parent.component.ts
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
tabs=['tab1','tab2']
data={}
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data={}
    
  }
  tabChange(event:any){
    console.log(event)
    let index=event.index
    this.data={}
    
  }
  hitinit(){
    this.data={id:"1",name:"sample"}
  }

}

parent.component.html
<div><mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="tabChange($event)" >
    <mat-tab  *ngFor="let tab of tabs;let i=index" #tabname>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            <span>{{tab}}</span>
        </ng-template>
    <app-child [isActive]="tabname.isActive" [data]="data"></app-child>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
<button (click)="hitinit()">Hit</button>
</div>


child.component.ts
export class ChildComponent  {
form=new FormGroup({
  name:new FormControl('')
});
id:any
@Input() public data:any
@Input() public isActive!:boolean
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.id=this.data.id
  }
 

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    console.log(this.isActive)
   
    this.method()
    
  }
  method(){
    if(this.isActive)
    this.form.patchValue(this.data)
  }

child.component.html
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input matInput formControlName="name"/>
</form>

As seen in the code provided, I have tried to use isActive boolean of mat-tab to call this.method() only for the tab that is active. However, this did not work.
Is it possible to make sure that ngOnChanges to be called only for active tab or avoid this kind of data sharing?
You can find the demo on stackblitz here:
https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/elisarelhan/testAngular

You have to maintain two objects that are unique to each tab, so that state is maintained for each tab, separately.
TS:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  tabs=['tab1','tab2']
  data: any=[{}, {}];
  index=  0;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data[0] = {id:"tab1"};
  }
  tabChange(event:any){
    console.log(event)
    this.index=event.index
    this.data={}
    if (this.tabs[this.index]==="tab1"){
     this. data[0]={id:"tab1",name:this.index}
    }
    else if(this.tabs[this.index]==="tab2"){
      this. data[1]={id:"tab2",name:this.index+'a'}
    }
  }
  hitinit(){
    this.data[this.index] = {id:"1",name:"sample"}
  }

}

HTML:
<div><mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="tabChange($event)" >
    <mat-tab  *ngFor="let tab of tabs;let i=index" #tabname>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            <span>{{tab}}</span>
        </ng-template>
    <app-child [isActive]="tabname.isActive" [data]="data[i]"></app-child>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
<button (click)="hitinit()">Hit</button>
</div>

Github Repo
